# How to call the Observer in REST API

Tags: magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, rest-api

I have the below observer event in my REST API .

```
        Mage::dispatchEvent('salesrule_validator_process', array(
            'rule'    => $rule,
            'item'    => $item,
            'address' => $address,
            'quote'   => $quote,
            'qty'     => $qty,
            'result'  => $result,
        ));
```

But this event handler is not triggering while  I executing through REST API in our module.

Please let me know how to call this observer in API. what are the configuration to be made in `config.xml`

Awaiting for your response.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add this in the `config.xml` under the `global` tag

```
<events>
    <salesrule_validator_process>
        <observers>
            <[some_unique_name_here]>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>[class_name_or_alias_here]</class>
                <method>methodToCall</method>
            </[some_unique_name_here]>
        </observers>
    </salesrule_validator_process>
</events>
```

clear the cache and you are done.

Comment: Hi Marius, thanks for information. I have the REST API for add the product into cart.  And extended Salesrule module into local directory.   I have added the above observer event code in addtocart module and salesrule module but still the event is not triggered . can you tell me what is the issue